# How can I update table data?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-core

how I update this data(In Image) for visualization

-------- "31-Jan"  to "31 :: Jan"

Pls, guide me.

[My Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3UND2.png)

Comment: The `Replace` method returns a string. It does not directly update the property. You would need to do `myProperty = myProperty.Replace("-", ":");`

Comment: `string.Replace()` _does not_ perform an in-place replacement. it _returns_ a string with the replaced values. ***you*** have to do something with it, like assign it to a variable. i recommend getting in the habit of [Reading Manuals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=net-5.0)

Comment: also: welcome to stackoverflow. i recommend [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), as well as reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not change that format at database. Your expected format you can use for visualization purpose. From the databases level it save as what format you used in DDL(data definition language).